# I close my intellij idea, choose [disconnect]

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I ran a project on `Intellij` , and then I closed my Intellij by choosing [disconnect] when I closed my Intellij. When I opened the program again to run my project, `Intellij` reminded me that port 8080 was occupied. I knew I could finish the project by killing port 8080. I wondered if there was any way that `Intellij` could end it directly.

I'm sorry that my English is not so good. It's translated online.

[image: This is my img]

Comment: Why do you use Disconnect? To stop the process you must choose Teminate, not Disconnect.

Comment: Using Windows,about  use Disconnect ,I just wanna try

Comment: I want to know, I performed this operation [Disconnect], I can find this program  again  from Intellij and terminate it, What should I do?

I know I can kill 8080 ports.I wonder if Intellij  can do it.

Comment: To check my understanding, you mean that you closed IntelliJ and chose the 'Disconnect' option, then, after you opened IntelliJ again, you want to find a way to access and stop the application which was started before you closed IntelliJ?

Comment: If my understanding is correct, then I don't think there's any way you can do this in IntelliJ - once you choose 'Disconnect' IntelliJ forgets all about that running process and doesn't look for it again when it restarts. The only option that I know of is to end the process manually through the tools in the operating system.

Comment: @DaveyDaveDave,
Yes! I just want to do that.If not，All right,Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can't terminate disconnected program from IDEA. You need to find it by port and then terminate it manually.

In Linux you may use something like this:

```
$ ss -tulpn | grep 8080
tcp     LISTEN   0        100                                         *:8080                        *:*            users:(("java",pid=1290385,fd=287))          
$ kill -2 1290385
```

`ss` command finds listening ports, `grep` finds port `8080`, `pid` is number of your process and then you terminate the process with `kill`.